# How to save multiple mongodb collections using Promise?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, es6-promise

using `async library` I can `save` data using below code

```
function save(callback){
  async.parallel([
        function(cb){
            Collection1.collection.insert(collections1,cb);
        },
        function(cb){
            Collection2.collection.insert(collections2,cb);
        },
        function(cb){
            Collection3.collection.insert(collections3,cb);
        }
    ],callback);
}
save(function(){
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

How I can modifiy `save` function so it will return `promise`?

```
save()
.then(function(){
  console.log('success');
})
.catch(function(){
  console.log('error');
})
```

Now my question is, How to write `save` function using promise without using `async library`??

```
function save(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
   //save collections here?? or any other way???
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes, save collections there, and call `resolve` on success, or `reject` on error.

Comment: I dont want to use async in save (question edited), How to do that?

Comment: Then don't use it. `insert` works perfectly without async. You can insert sequentially without async. You can insert into single collection per promise, and use `Promise.all`. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for inspiration.

Comment: `Collection1.collection.insert` is not returning promise, so how we can achieve this?

Comment: No, `insert` does not return a promise. Your `save` function does.

Comment: Sample code would be much appreciated..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) inside `save` function, then you are able to use it as you expect

```
function save(){
    var promises = [
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Collection1.collection.insert(collections1, function(err, done){
                 if(err)
                     reject(err);
                 else
                     resolve(done);
            });
        }),
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Collection2.collection.insert(collections2, function(err, done){
                 if(err)
                     reject(err);
                 else
                     resolve(done);
            });
        }),
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Collection3.collection.insert(collections3, function(err, done){
                 if(err)
                     reject(err);
                 else
                     resolve(done);
            });
        })
    ];
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

save().then(function(){
   console.log('success');
}).catch(function(){
   console.log('error');
})
```

Comment: Why are you treating `Collection3` differently than `Collection1` and `Collection2`?

Comment: For the sake of example, to show that it's possible

Comment: There's not much of a choice. Assuming that it is supposed to work like `async.parallel`, the first is just wrong and you need to do it like in the last for all of them.

Comment: No, `Collection2.collection.insert(collections2, resolve);` resolves it anyway no matter what's the result of insertion - because we don't bother the response of promise in `save().then`, that's why we call `resolve` which will execute always, That's why i wrote _you could check result of insertion_. It can be treated differently, some may explicitly return useful information from promise, some just expects execution and don't need result

Comment: Yes, it resolves anyway, and that's exactly the problem - in the case of an error it should be rejected, so that `Promise.all` can propagate the problem. In fact *every* should return useful information.

Comment: Ok, updated answer for you @Bergi. My intention was to show promise, not callback construction indeed, thanks anyway, ...maybe know i deserve your upvote?