# using promise with google calendar insert event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

I have an implementation in which I call the google calendar create event from 2 functions. Each time multiple events might be created. After success event creation, i save the return data in my local database. the issue i'm facing is before all events can be completed, the page reloads and most events are unable to save in local database. I tried using `$().ajaxStop({});` but maybe i'm doing something wrong so it is not working. Also currently i'm doing it using `$.when` but still the same problem. How to properly implement promise in the below scenario? Any help is appreciated.

```
// Google Calendar Insert event start
function handleInsert(id, event){
    var cal_det = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('calendarId'));
    var CALENDAR_ID = cal_det.calendar_id;
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        'calendarId': CALENDAR_ID,
        'resource': event
    });     
    request.execute(function(gres) {
        console.log('Event created: ' + gres.htmlLink);
        // this here is used to update my local database.
        $.getJSON(baseUrl+'<Some URL>', {id: id, value: gres},     function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
}


// Google calendar insert event end
function syncAppointment(){
    var form = $("#google-sync"); 
    var submiturl = $(form).attr('action'); 
    form.find('.has-error').remove(); 
    $.post( submiturl, form.serialize(), function(response) {
        if(!response.message){
            var j = 0, l = response.length;
            $.each( response, function( key, value ) { 
                 handleInsert(key,value);
                 // this here creates event.
            });
        } else {
            alert(response.message);
        }
    }, "json").done(function() {
        console.log( "Success." );
    }).fail(function() {    
        console.log( "Some error occured. Please try after some time." );
    }).always(function() {  
        console.log( "Completed." );
        window.location.reload();
    });
}


var form = $("#AppointmentAgendaForm"); var submiturl =     $(form).attr('action');
if(validateForm(form) == true){
    $.post( submiturl, form.serialize(), function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (!response.error && !response.message && !response.appointments) {
            alert('Nomination (s) a été créé. Nous avons désactivé les créneaux horaires pour les engagements professionnels pour la période de temps définie.');
            $.when.apply($, $.map(response, function( key, value ) {
                handleInsert(value,key);                    
                // this here is second call. this implementation should work but does not...
            })).done(function() { window.location.reload();  /* all ajax calls done now */ });
        } else {
        }
    }, "json").done(function() {
        console.log( "Success." );
        setTimeout(function(){ $(form).find('p.has-error').remove(); }, 3000);
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log( "Some error occured. Please try after some time." );
    }).always(function() {
        console.log( "Completed." );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use [**Promise.all()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) inside saving function. As discussed in the documentation,

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.

This same method was used in this SO post - [How to save multiple mongodb collections using Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381423/how-to-save-multiple-mongodb-collections-using-promise?rq=1). Sample code on how to implement `promise.all()` can found in the given SO post and in the documentation. I hope that addresses your concern.

Comment: bit late to reply, i'll try this. although i overcame the issue by modifying the structure of the implementation.